# Problem with align command

Tags: spacing, align

I faced a weird situation when using "Align" command. Here is what I write

```
Since $ l $ is fixed, $ \sum_{k=0}^{l-1} k^i \cos (2k \theta) $ and $ \sum_{k=0}^{l-1} k^i \sin (2k \theta) $ are bounded for $ i=0,1,2 $, using \textbf{Cor. 1.1.1} we have
\begin{align*}
    B_W^2 &:= \mathrm{Var}(W'_n ( \theta))\\
    &= \mathrm{Var} (- \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \sum_{k=0}^{l-1} a_{2jl+k} ( (2j+1/2)l+k )  \sin ((2j+1/2)l+k) \theta ) \\
    &= \sum_j \sum_k \left( (4j^2 + 2j +1/4)l^2 + (4j+1)lk +k^2 \right) \frac{1 - \cos ((4j+1)l + 2k) \theta}{2} \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_j \left( l^3 (4j^2 + 2j +1/4) + \frac{l^3 -l^2 }{2}(4j+1) +  \frac{2l^3 - 3l^2 + l }{6} \right) \\
    &- \frac{1}{2} \sum_j \sum_k \left( (4j^2 + 2j +1/4)l^2 + (4j+1)lk +k^2 \right) \cos ((4j+1)l + 2k) \theta \\
    &= \frac{2l^3m^3}{3} + \mathcal{O}(m^2) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_j \sum_k \left( (4j^2 + 2j +1/4)l^2 + (4j+1)lk +k^2 \right) \cos ((4j+1)l + 2k) \theta \\
    &= \frac{2l^3m^3}{3} + \mathcal{O}(m^2) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_j \sum_k \left( (4j^2 + 2j +1/4)l^2 + (4j+1)lk +k^2 \right) \cos (4j+1)l \theta \cos (2k) \theta \\
    &+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_j \sum_k \left( (4j^2 + 2j +1/4)l^2 + (4j+1)lk +k^2 \right) \sin (4j+1)l \theta \sin (2k) \theta \\
    &= \frac{n^3}{12} + \mathcal{O}(n^2) - \frac{l^2}{2} (4P_2 (l \theta ) + 2P_1 (l \theta ) + 1/4) \sum_k \cos (2k) \theta \\
    &+ \frac{l^2}{2} (4Q_2 (l \theta ) + 2Q_1 (l \theta ) + 1/4) \sum_k \sin (2k) \theta - \frac{l}{2} (4P_1 (l \theta ) + 1) \sum_k k \cos (2k) \theta \\
    &+ \frac{l}{2} (4Q_1 (l \theta ) + 1) \sum_k k \sin (2k) \theta - \frac{1}{2} P_0 (l \theta ) \sum_k k^2 \cos (2k) \theta + \frac{1}{2} Q_0 (l \theta ) \sum_k k^2 \sin (2k) \theta \\
    &= \frac{n^3}{12} + \mathcal{O}(n^2)+ \mathcal{O}(\frac{m^2}{\epsilon}) = \frac{n^3}{12} + \mathcal{O}(n^2).
\end{align*}
```

but there is huge gap between the last sentence and the next line as you see in the picture. What shall I do? 
P.S. When I add `\newpage`, everything is back to normal. I thing the problem is with margins or something like that.
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question so that we have a complete MWE - a minimum working example. That's a compilable document edited down as small as can be that still shows the problem.

Comment: Add `\raggedbottom` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @ Henri It solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by unbreakable material after the alignment which was not part of the MWE.  This will most likely not be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the texts and floats around the equation, not the equation itself. What LaTeX is doing is fill the page by stretching the space between the text and the equation. Check this:

[image]

Now remove some text from the paragraph after the equation:

[image]

LaTeX has increased the white space. Why? Because it is trying to avoid line breaking so it tries to fill the column with whole paragraphs.

Now remove more text:

[image]

As you can see, removing more text caused the section of the next column to be written after the paragraph. Three lines aren't really that bad in terms of their appearance so latex accepts that. Otherwise, LaTeX will push the conclusions section to the next column and try to fill the first column by increasing the white space.

The solution here is to work on what is *around* the equation, including floats, not only the text itself. Also, try tuning these parameters in the preamble.

`\predisplaypenalty=1000`: penalty for breaking before an equation (default: 1000)
`\postdisplaypenalty=0`: penalty for breaking after an equation (default: 0)

Comment: How is adjusting `\predisplaypenalty` and `\postdisplaypenalty` going to affect unbreakable material after an equation?

Comment: it's very strange that there is more space above the equation than below.  you don't happen to have a blank line before the equation, do you?  it you don't, then i would like to see the exact input, because in that case, this looks either like a bug, or the preset skips above and below the display have been modified.

Comment: @HenriMenke I didn't mean to steal your suggestion. I mentioned your name while posting it. I deleted the answer. Tnx again for your help.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The math italics `PMARE` and `max` suggest strongly that this is a cause of erroneous input.

Comment: The equations are generated properly and the complier does not return any issues. It is just a matter of LaTeX trying to maintain a pleasing appearance of documents. Sometimes the algorithms fail and LaTeX does not find a solution due several reasons such as the complexity of the page, typesetter insisting on floats being in certain locations, or some weakness in the algorithms that place the floats.

Comment: What you wrote about linebreaking is wrong. The issue is caused by 'flushbottom' option used it books. Also, use the command '\max' to typeset max in roman.

Comment: @HenriMenke -- oh, i agree that there is erroneous input, but since we haven't seen what it was, the question about the blank line still stands -- if there *wasn't* a blank line, then the definition of the skips must be questioned, and that's not an area that a novice usually meddles with, although the suggestion regarding the penalties hints that this person may have done so.  in any event, the spacing above and below the equation is just plain wrong, and i would like to know why.